# How can I extract unique data from Excel to a table in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, if-statement, unique

I have a dataset from an Excel sheet that contains District Name and Course Code as columns. This data is at a student registration level, which is why Districts are presented multiple times.
Looking something like this:

| District Name | Course Code |
| --- | --- |
| District 1 | Course A |
| District 1 | Course A |
| District 2 | Course A |
| District 2 | Course B |
| District 2 | Course B |
| District 2 | Course D |
| District 3 | Course B |
| District 3 | Course C |

I am looking to extract districts WITHOUT courses a, b, OR c.

I would like to have a table that would return something like the following:

| District Name | Course A | Course B | Course C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| District 1 | yes | no | no |
| District 2 | yes | yes | no |
| District 3 | no | yes | yes |

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Not clear about the expected.  Can you show the expected

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. However, I am looking to have a table that shows which districts have or don't have courses a, b, c, or d. It would be preferable if the table was structured to where it returns "yes" when a district does offer the course and "no" when the district does not offer the course.

Comment: In the example input, I guess District1 will not be selected?

Comment: Read in your excel sheet with the package `readxl`. Then use the `filter` function from `dplyr` to filter all your courses for only "no" values in A, B, C, and D.

Comment: Your desired output (4 columns) is not the same as the statement *"extract districts without courses..."*. If you need to know how to pivot a table from "long" to "wide" format, there are plenty of questions about that on SO. If you need to know how to filter based on presence of multiple rows within a group, `dplyr`'s combination of `group_by`, `filter`, and `any`/`all` are the functions you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Perhaps you just need to pivot from "long" to "wide"?

```r
dat <- structure(list(District.Name = c("District 1", "District 1", "District 2", "District 2", "District 2", "District 2", "District 3", "District 3"), Course.Code = c("Course A", "Course A", "Course A", "Course B", "Course B", "Course D", "Course B", "Course C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(a = TRUE) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from="Course.Code", values_from="a", values_fill=FALSE, values_fn=any)
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   District.Name `Course A` `Course B` `Course D` `Course C`
#   <chr>         <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>     
# 1 District 1    TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
# 2 District 2    TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       FALSE     
# 3 District 3    FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      TRUE
```

The temporary `a` column is really just a placeholder. Necessary, temporary, no long-term impact.

---

### Previous answer

I think it might be best to separate the logic into two steps: (1) read in from an excel file; and (2) filter rows.

The first is straight-forward using either of the `readxl` or `openxlsx` packages. I'll show using both here, but will use `dat2` for the rest of the answer.

```r
dat1 <- openxlsx::readWorkbook("~/StackOverflow/14617210/Book1.xlsx", sheet = 1)
dat2 <- readxl::read_excel("~/StackOverflow/14617210/Book1.xlsx")
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   `district name` `course A` `course B` `course C` `course D`
#   <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 District 1      no         yes        yes        no        
# 2 District 2      no         no         no         no        
# 3 District 3      yes        yes        yes        yes
```

Notes:

- the column names for `dat1` are munged regardless of `check.names=`, with an open issue at https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/33, migrated from https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/102. So while reading them in is easily in both, the answer for `dat2` will need to be adjusted if you prefer `openxlsx`'s import.
- since the column names in `dat2` have spaces in them, we need to enclose the names in backticks (e.g., `` `course A` ``); if the real column names do not have spaces, or if you choose `dat1` where names are "fixed" to replace spaces with dots (e.g., `course.A`, then the backticks are not required).
- I'm assuming that the `course` columns are contiguous, so that a "sequence" of columns (e.g., `` `course A`:`course D` ``) makes sense. It is feasible to do column-selection in other ways, including `grep(..., value=TRUE)` and similar.

Your second task (filter the data) is straight-forward in any of the dialects of R. It is not clear to me exactly how your logic for filtering should go, so I'll demonstrate several variants.

1. Show those districts that contain *none* of the courses (all are `"no"`):

   ```r
   # base R
   dat2[rowSums(subset(dat2, select = `course A`:`course D`) == "yes") == 0, ]
   # # A tibble: 1 x 5
   #   `district name` `course A` `course B` `course C` `course D`
   #   <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
   # 1 District 2      no         no         no         no        

   # dplyr
   library(dplyr)
   dat2 %>%
     filter(across(`course A`:`course D`, ~ . == "no"))
   ```
2. Show courses that have at least 1 "no":

   ```r
   # base R
   dat2[rowSums(subset(dat2, select = `course A`:`course D`) == "no") > 0, ]
   # # A tibble: 2 x 5
   #   `district name` `course A` `course B` `course C` `course D`
   #   <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
   # 1 District 1      no         yes        yes        no        
   # 2 District 2      no         no         no         no        

   # dplyr
   dat2 %>%
     filter(rowSums(across(`course A`:`course D`, ~ . == "no")) > 0)
   ```

---

Sample data, CSV here, pasted into a spreadsheet and saved as `Book1.xlsx`:

```
district name,course A,course B,course C,course D
District 1,no,yes,yes,no
District 2,no,no,no,no
District 3,yes,yes,yes,yes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! However, I think I should have explained the format of my current dataset a lot better. I believe I could also use a similar approach, correct? Would I need to apply a distinct or unique function considering district names can come out more than once since data is at a student registration level?

Thank you, once again!